# goland IDE - build using ldflags

Tags: go, build

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.subversion=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`"
```

works fine in command line,

but goland ide fails when adding the same flags to my go build configuration > Go tool arguments:

```
-ldflags "-X main.subversion=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`"
```

it seems to be having problems escaping the double quotes, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

-- edit:

in the run tab I see:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/..../go #gosetup
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin/go build -ldflags "-X main.subversion=$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)" -o /Users/..../Downloads/ta_mac . #gosetup

invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
Compilation finished with exit code 2
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

although if I do run manually the same command, it succeeds and the app produces the expected behavioud with the correct value for the variable subversion.

```
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin/go build -ldflags "-X main.subversion=$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)" -o /Users/..../Downloads/ta_mac . #gosetup
```

---edit2:

am alternatively exploring using

```
GOFLAGS="-ldflags=-X main.subversion=$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)"
```

but am bumping into a similar problem so far

---edit3:

one more option would seem to create a makefile, but have been looking into this for hours now so I'll pause before looking into this option, which may be overly complex for what I need to do

---edit4:
jetbrains suggested to use this syntax under Go tool arguments:

```
-ldflags "-X 'main.subversion=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`'"
```

while this does not raise an error, it also does not produce the expected behaviour: the subversion variable is literally assigned the string:

```
`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`
```

while obviously I'd expect to be something like

`20231231.235959`

I tried similar alternatives to no avail:

```
-ldflags "-X 'main.subversion=$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)'"
-ldflags "-X 'main.subversion='$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)"
-ldflags "-X 'main.subversion=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`'"
-ldflags "-X 'main.subversion='`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`"
-ldflags "-X \"main.subversion=$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)\""
-ldflags "-X \"main.subversion=\"$(date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)"
-ldflags "-X \"main.subversion=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`\""
-ldflags "-X \"main.subversion=\"`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`"
```

Comment: did you solve it ?  I see the same if I pass Go tool arguments: `-ldflags "-X 'main.version=$(cat VERSION)'"`